# is there any way to remove subject from each line of the rspec code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to remove subject from each line,it's making my spec too verbose,

my model has the following code :-

describe "#clone_for_resubmit" do

```
let(:new_item) { @order_item1.clone_for_resubmit(:cart_group => @cart_group, :cloned_collections => { }, :order => @cart_group.order, :message => "this is just for testing purpose", :receiver => "example@example.com", :sender =>"ragarwal@kreeti.com" ) }
subject{ new_item}
it "should clone an order_item" do
  gift = FactoryGirl.create(:gift, :order_item_id => @order_item1.id, :user => @user)
 subject.cart_group.should == @cart_group
  subject.collection.name.should == @order_item1.collection.name
  subject.collection.book.title.should == @order_item1.collection.book.title
  subject.collection.user.should == @order_item1.collection.user
  subject.collection.book.book_chapters.count.should == @order_item1.collection.book.book_chapters.count
  subject.collection.book.book_chapters.last.chapter_title.should == @order_item1.collection.book.book_chapters.last.chapter_title
  subject.collection.items.last.user_recipe.recipe.name.should == @order_item1.collection.items.last.user_recipe.recipe.name
 subject.collection.book.book_chapters.last.items.last.user_recipe.recipe.name.should == @order_item1.collection.book.book_chapters.last.items.last.user_recipe.recipe.name
  subject.gift.recipient_email.should == gift.recipient_email
  subject.gift.message.should == "this is just for testing purpose"
  subject.gift.receiver.should == "example@example.com"
  subject.gift.sender.should == "ragajhk@vy.com"
  subject.payment.payment_amount.should == @order_item1.payment.payment_amount
  subject.payment.order.should == @cart_group.order
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

David Chelimsky describes [implicit use of 'subject' as a code smell](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/), so you're right to want to get rid of it.  However your `it` block is doing way too much which is going to impact the readability of your spec massively anyway - to make it more readable, I'd recommend doing something more like the following:

```
describe Order do
  describe '#clone_for_resubmit' do
    before do
      # @user = ...
      # @order_item1 = ...          
      # @cart_group = ...          
      @new_item = @order_item1.clone_for_resubmit(:cart_group         => @cart_group,
                                                  :cloned_collections => { },                                                      
                                                  :order              => @cart_group.order,
                                                  :message            => "this is just for testing purpose",
                                                  :receiver           => "example@example.com",
                                                  :sender             =>"ragarwal@kreeti.com" ) }

      @gift = FactoryGirl.create(:gift, :order_item_id => @order_item1.id, :user => @user)
    end

    it 'should use the correct cart group' do
      @new_item.cart_group.should == @cart_group
    end

    it 'should use the correct collection name' do
      @new_item.collection.name.should == @order_item1.collection.name
    end

    it 'should use the correct book title' do
      # etc...
    end
  end
end
```

That way, you'll not only have much more readable specs, they'll also fail more nicely - if one thing goes wrong, the others will still be green.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, is there any way to remove @new_item from every it block? with the help of "subject" i guess and again writing subject in each and every block will make it verbose, what should be the shortest way to write this kind of spec without repeating variables/subject

Comment: `subject` takes an argument allowing you to specify a name other than 'subject' - so you could have something like `subject(:item) { new_item }; ..... item.cart_group.should == @cart_group... #etc`.  However bear in mind that 'the shortest way' is often not the most readable way!

Comment: oww thank u so much omnikron for the help :) this is what i wanted to know